# Make QTMovieView full screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, quicktime

I have a QTMovieView set up as an IBOutlet.  I want to play the video in full screen.  Which method allows this?

Answer (score 1):

See QTKit sample code at: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/MyMediaPlayer/listing3.html specifically the "goFullScreen" method.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://api.monobjc.net/html/M_Monobjc_Cocoa_NSView_EnterFullScreenModeWithOptions_2_fd6ad6ce.htm) help?

[Here's](http://api.monobjc.net/html/T_Monobjc_QuickTime_QTMovieView.htm) a pretty detailed list of all the methods.

Comment: Er. Monobjc? The tags clearly say that the questioner is using Objective-C, not C#. Better to use http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/ for the class, and http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: for the enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: method.

Comment: Does enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: also give me the movie controls that you get when you play a movie in full screen mode in QuickTime Player?